# Changing a button's text after an event

Tags: vb.net, button, visual-studio-2013

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Member = False Then
        LoginForm1.Show()
    Else <<<<(-after logged in successfully-)
        Button1.Text = "Logged In" <<<(-I want to change this button text to Logged In-)
        Button1.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

So my problem is, the `Button1.Text` changes only works when I click on the button. If I did not click on the button, the text is still same as default **"Login"**. I want to make the button text change instantly after the `loginform1` closes. Help please and thank you

Comment: *loginform1 closes* you mean loginform1 **opens**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LoginForm1.ShowDialog() instead. This shows the login as a modal form. This means you can not access the underlying form and the code execution in your sub stops until the modal form is closed.

So you could just use:

```
LoginForm1.ShowDialog()
If Member = True Then  'I guess this is how you check if the login was successful
   Button1.Text = "Logged in"
   Button1.Enabled = false
End if
```

instead of the whole If-Else-EndIf.

Comment: Thanks alot for the guide. Works like a charm! How do i give likes or reputation to you? Sorry, im new to forums and stuff

Comment: No problem. On SO you up- or downvote answers by using the arrow up/down symbols to the left of the post. You further accept answers that fit your problem as you have already done.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in LoginForm1 when the Member has logged in you should include this code:

```
FORM1.Button1.Text = "Logged In"
FORM1.Button1.Enabled = False
```

Replace `FORM1` with the name of your first form. (Form containing Button1_Click)